# On prüfer group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, infinite-groups

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group), for a prime $p$,

The Prüfer p-group may be represented as a subgroup of the circle group, $U(1)$, as the set of $p^n$th roots of unity as $n$ ranges over all non-negative integers:

$\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)=\{\exp(2\pi i m/p^n) \mid m\in \mathbf{Z}^+,\,n\in \mathbf{Z}^+\}=G.$

Alternatively, the Prüfer p-group may be seen as the Sylow $p-$subgroup of $Q/Z$, consisting of those elements whose order is a power of $p$:

$\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty)=\mathbb{Z}[1/p]/\mathbb{Z}=H$

I have a very hard time to prove that the group $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you find an isomorphism between the unit circle in $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @Nishant You either mean the torsion subgroup of the unit circle, or $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$.

Comment: The first one, sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ask yourself: what do elements of each look like?

You should think $e^{2\pi i\color{Red}{\square}}$ in $G$, and $\color{Red}{\square}+\Bbb Z$ in $H$, with both $\color{Red}{\square}$s looking exactly the same...

Comment: $f:H \rightarrow G$, by $f(m/p^n+Z) = \exp(2\pi i m/p^n)$